# Your role configuration do not allow you Assign Roles for Test Plans : Testlink Error

Tags: testing, testlink

Login to Testlink
Go to User Management
Go to Assign Test Plan Roles
User will be able to see some error and below message as warning.

```
Your role configuration do not allow you Assign Roles for Test Plans
```

What could be the possible reason for this issue and how to handle this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I faced this issue and realized this is `bug` in `testlink`. To handle this issue for now, login to testlink as `admin` and add a `testplan` for your project. this error will not be shown.

So as per my understanding on this page exception for no test plan is not handled.